# I'm using an action "Get Secrets" in power automate to get all the azure key vault secrets. Even though there are 25 records it is returning only 19

Tags: power-automate

I'm using an action "Get Secrets" in power automate to get all the azure key vault secrets. Get Records has a max limit of 25 rows. My azure key vault has more than that. Even then it is returning only 19 rows instead of 25. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

It is supposed to get 25 rows at least but it is getting only 19 rows.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.